# Usefulness of Damgård–Jurik

Tags: encryption, public-key, algorithm-design, paillier

I am trying to understand what are the benefits of using [Damgård–Jurik](https://people.csail.mit.edu/rivest/voting/papers/DamgardJurikNielsen-AGeneralizationOfPailliersPublicKeySystemWithApplicationsToElectronicVoting.pdf) over Paillier. I understand that expansion factor decreases as `s` increases. But isn't it the case that this comes at the expense of security? If your goal is to reduce space overhead compared to Paillier then you might choose a smaller security parameter and a higher value for `s`. Or to put it otherwise for a fixed security parameter as `s` increases cipher-text size increases. So why not just use Paillier with a smaller security parameter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Damgård-Jurik, not only expansion factor is decreased: this scheme improves state of the art.

Reducing size of prime factors makes better chance of factoriation or maybe solving particular decision problem that Paillier scheme depends on.

Comment: Are you suggesting that there is a way to reduce cipher text space overhead in DJ without reducing the size of prime factors (which is what i refer to as security parameter)? Could you give an example?

Comment: DJ did not claim any overhead, right? They claimed expansion factor. I'm suggesting against reducing bitsize of primes (security parameter), that results in decreasing hardness of factoring. Increasing $s$ will not make factoring any harder.